# How to get URL from kinesis video streams with GetHLSStreamingSessionURL

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am trying to get a URL to view my video on kinesis video streams with getHLSStreamingSessionURL.

On postman I have created a POST call to 'https://endpoint/getHLSStreamingSessionURL

On postman I get a 200 response but the response body is :

```
{
    "Output": {
        "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
    },
    "Version": "1.0"
}
```

I expect the response to return a HLS url.

And here is my request body:

```
{
   "ContainerFormat": "FRAGMENTED_MP4",
   "DiscontinuityMode": "ON_DISCONTINUITY",
   "DisplayFragmentTimestamp": "ALWAYS",
   "Expires": 300,
   "HLSFragmentSelector": { 
      "FragmentSelectorType": "PRODUCER_TIMESTAMP",
       "TimestampRange": { 
        "EndTimestamp": 1646055362163,
        "StartTimestamp": 1646055362143
      }
   },
   "PlaybackMode": "ON-DEMAND",
   "StreamName": "DEV_videoStreamTest"
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my http request and explain what exactly this response means?

Answer (score 1):

I found this a bit convoluted, but you need to make a call to
[GetDataEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_GetDataEndpoint.html) first in order to get the correct API endpoint url to make the call to [GetHLSStreamingSessionURL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_reader_GetHLSStreamingSessionURL.html).

There's a great full example on the AWS Github, and you can use that to try out all the parameters:
[amazon-kinesis-video-streams-media-viewer](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-media-viewer)

But in short, the call to

```
https://kinesisvideo.<region>.amazonaws.com/getDataEndpoint
```

returns something like this:

```
{ "DataEndpoint": "https://b-1234xyz.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" }
```

then you make the call to **getHLSStreamingSessionURL** replacing your base url:

```
https://b-1234xyz.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getHLSStreamingSessionURL
```

I'm using boto3, so here's my simplified example in python:

```py
import boto3

# Get the API URL
kinesis_client = boto3.client("kinesisvideo")
response = kinesis_client.get_data_endpoint(
    StreamName=stream_name,
    APIName="GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL"
)
endpoint_url = response.get("DataEndpoint")

# Get the Stream URL
kinesis_client = boto3.client(
    "kinesis-video-archived-media",
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url
)
response = kinesis_client.get_hls_streaming_session_url(
    StreamName=stream_name,
    ...
)
```